# WooCommerce - how can I add a custom made footer (page element) under single_product_page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been working on my first Wordpress shop for days now and there are some problems which I have troubles resolving.

Page https://gonion.pl/product/hoodie/

First one:
Woocommerce - I need to add the same footer that is visible everywhere on the page to the single_product_page.

I have been reading about Wordpress hooks but I don't know how to use them.
The footer is created as a page element in WPBakery Page Builder, not as a footer per se.

Second one:
On blank cart page https://gonion.pl/basket/ there is a blank space under the footer - how could I get rid of it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This woocommerce visual hook guide helped me a lot in my first shop

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

About the hooks take a look at the official documentation

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

this is what you are looking for:

```
add_action( 'action_name', 'your_function_name' );

function your_function_name() {
// Your code
}
```